# How to update a document and avoid duplicates in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I've a problem with a query in MongoDB, the main idea is that I have a collection of user represented like this :

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("53e4ac672a486e660a6fe930"),
   "username" : "foo",
   "firstname" : "bar",
   "lastname" : "foobar"
}
```

And I would like to insert in a collection named `feeds` of feed represented like this :

```
{
   "username" : "john",
   "readed" : 0
}
```

The expected result should be look like this :

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("53e4ac672a486e660a6fe930"),
   "username" : "foo",
   "firstname" : "bar",
   "lastname" : "foobar",
   "feeds" : [
       {
          "username" : "bob",
          "readed" : 0
       },
       {
          "username" : "john",
          "readed" : 1
       },
    ]
}
```

For the moment, I use a update to perform this :

```
db.account.update({username: 'foo'}, 
                  {$addToSet: {feeds: {username: 'john', readed: 0}}})
```

But I've duplicate like this :

```
   "feeds" : [
       {
          "username" : "bob",
          "readed" : 0
       },
       {
          "username" : "john", <--- NOT WANTED
          "readed" : 0
       },
       {
          "username" : "john",
          "readed" : 1
       },
    ]
```

How to create a new field if it not exist ?

Comment: robbrit below is correct.  There is no single mongodb update that will handle your use case.  You are trying to atomically update the "readed" value if the element of the array exists, but insert it if it doesn't.  $addToSet only handles the "insert the whole element if it doesn't exist" case.  You might be able to do this by somehow getting the feeds member into the query of the update with what the expected value is, but this would involve a 2nd query to figure out the current value in the first place.  This would make the whole update like an optimistic lock scenario.

Comment: Does this help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7945583/mongodb-can-a-inc-increment-a-value-inside-a-addtoset Do an addToSet followed by an inc as separate queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it like this. In the eyes of Mongo:

```
{username: "john", readed: 1}
```

and

```
{username: "john", readed: 0}
```

are not the same, so `$addToSet` will not merge them.

Answer (score 1):

In your case as you don't want to update the `readed` field with the latest value, you can indeed do this in a single query, though `$ne` is inefficient to use generally

`db.account.update({username: "foo","feeds.username":{"$ne":"john"}},
              {"$push":{feeds:{username:"john","readed":0}}})`;

It is not so trivial if you want to update the field with latest value. The `$` is not supported with `upsert`. Check [this issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3326). So you will need to make more than one query.